# Extract all text except the last word from a column using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

Let's say I have a column in my items table called `name`:

```
name
----
Wrench
Hammer (label1)
Screwdriver (label1) (label2)
Tape Measure (label1) (label2) (label3)
```

I want to write a PostgreSQL query to extract all text except the last label (if it exists). So given the data above, I want to end up with:

```
substring
---------
Wrench
Hammer
Screwdriver (label1)
Tape Measure (label1) (label2)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use substring and a regular expression.

The syntax is:

```
substring(string, regularExpression)
```

The regular expression should use () to delimit what part of the string to extract. For example:

```
substring('abcef', 'b(..)')
```

will return 'ce', the two characters that follow b. If the regular expression does not match the string it returns NULL.

Specifically in this case:

```
dmg@[local] # select substring('Hammer (label1)' from '^(.+)\([^\)]+\)$')   ;
 substring 
-----------
 Hammer 
(1 row)

dmg@[local] # select substring('Tape Measure (label1) (label2) (label3)' from '^(.+)\([^\)]+\)$')   ;
            substring            
---------------------------------
 Tape Measure (label1) (label2) 
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace()` is a simple way to handle this:

```
select v.name,
       regexp_replace(name, ' [(][^)]+[)]$', '')
from (values 
       ('Wrench'),
       ('Hammer (label1)'),
       ('Screwdriver (label1) (label2)'),
       ('Tape Measure (label1) (label2) (label3)')
     ) v(name);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=85822273d3733ee0f92af88bd41305b4) is a db<>fiddle.